# JSON_VALUE is not working in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, json-value

I have JSON data in a column in my table. I am trying to apply where condition on the JSON column and fetch records.

`Employee` table:

[image]

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, EMP_NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
WHERE JSON_VALUE(TEAM, '$') IN (2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10)
```

I am getting an empty result when I use this query. Any help on how to do this?

Comment: What is the expected output and what do you want to do?

Comment: @Zhorov expected output ID,EMP_NAME where team is in 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 7 or 10

Comment: @Larnu what would be the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON in the `TEAM` column with `OPENJSON()`:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
   ID int,
   EMP_NAME varchar(50),
   TEAM varchar(1000)
)
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE (ID, EMP_NAME, TEAM)
VALUES
   (1, 'Name1', '[2,11]'),
   (2, 'Name2', '[2,3,4,5,7,10]'),
   (3, 'Name3', NULL)
```

Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.ID, e.EMP_NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(e.TEAM) WITH (TEAM int '$') j
WHERE j.TEAM IN (2,3,4,5,7,10)
```

Result:

```
ID  EMP_NAME
1   Name1
2   Name2
```

As an additional option, if you want to get the matches as an aggregated text, you may use the following statement (SQL Server 2017 is needed):

```
SELECT e.ID, e.EMP_NAME, a.TEAM
FROM EMPLOYEE e
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT STRING_AGG(TEAM, ',') AS TEAM
   FROM OPENJSON(e.TEAM) WITH (TEAM int '$')
   WHERE TEAM IN (2,3,4,5,7,10) 
) a
WHERE a.TEAM IS NOT NULL
```

Result:

```
ID  EMP_NAME TEAM
1   Name1    2
2   Name2    2,3,4,5,7,10
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON_VALUE` returns a **scalar** value, not a data set, which you appaer to think it would. If you run `SELECT JSON_VALUE('[2,3,4,5,7,10]','$')` you'll see that it returns `NULL`, so yes, no rows will be returned.

You need to treat the JSON like a data set, not a single value:

```
SELECT ID, EMP_NAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE E
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM OPENJSON (E.TEAM) OJ
              WHERE OJ.Value IN (2,3,4,5,7,10))
```

Comment: The approach with `EXISTS` is also an option, +1.

Comment: Yeah, i went this method, as yours may return multiple rows, and I assumed the OP wants a single one, @Zhorov .